# Json file links working in local, but not in production

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've a JSON file in assets and my radio app works fine in local, streaming from the links given, however in prod, the names of the list show but whenever I click on play, it's unable to play the links, I am not able to figure out why

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=noad.radio

When I install the same app through debug mode directly I works fine, the links play music, when uploaded to playstore it doesn't

JSON is as such

[{
"name": "90s Super Hits live",
"url": "http://103.16.47.70:7444/;stream.mp3",
"language": "hindi"
}, {
"name": "90s Super Hits live2",
"url": "http://103.16.47.70:7222/;stream.mp3",
"language": "hindi"
}, {
"name": "90s SuperHits",
"url": "http://103.16.47.70:7444/;stream?type=http&nocache=10",
"language": "hindi"
}]

And I've android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in main AndroidManifest.XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this as a permission issue, as I didn't add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And my app needed internet permission to play the streams, it worked locally, and in prod it didn't

Post adding this, it's working as required

To check the behavior of prod, use

```
Flutter run --release
```